# file upload insert url images

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible with jquery:

When i have a simple upload file

```
<input type="file" />
```

and a

```
<img src="http://www.my.com/images/myimage.png">
```

when I click on the image to use the url image as file to upload?

Any approaches?

Comment: I'm not following... why would you want to upload an image that is already embedded on your page?

Comment: @Moses  - he's asking if he can have an image act as a button to engage the file upload.

Answer (score 3):

It can only be done through javascript, however most browsers won't let you due to security reasons. IE will though, dont know if all version will or not.

```
<img src="images/flake.gif" name="flake" onclick="openUploadFileDialogue();">
<script>
function openUploadFileDialogue(){
    var frm = document.form1.upload;
    if(document.all && document.getElementById){
        document.form1.upload.click();
    }
}
</script>
```

You **COULD** [style your upload element with CSS](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/02/styling-file-upload-select-input-control-input-typefile.html) to get the desired result depending on what the desired result is.

Comment: This does work in most browsers, not Opera and not older versions of Firefox.